# Custom checkbox appearance lines up differently with labels than text inputs

Tags: css

I'm trying to custom style a checkbox in a form using `-webkit-appearance: none;` so I get full control.

The problem is that I can't seem to get it to line up with labels like the other text fields, even though it's got the same height, margins, padding, etc.  It looks like this:

[JSFiddle Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/9Fse5/)

So why does the checkbox not align like the text fields do? The checkbox seems to align it's bottom with the label, where the text fields aligns their middles with the label.

[image: form example]

**Relevant CSS:**

```
label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80px;
    height: 34px;
}

input[type=text], input[type=checkbox] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 34px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
    width: 34px; /* make it square */
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked {
    background: green;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add: `vertical-align: middle;` to your checkbox styling. Here's [an adjusted fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Fse5/1/).

Also, keep in mind that styling checkboxes is not very cross-browser compatible. Firefox doesn't let you easily reset the appearance. You can add `-moz-appearance: none`, but that won't get rid of everything. You're probably better off styling a label that toggles the checkbox and hiding the actual input element.